# R cannot be resolved, error installing Android Plugin

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I've just created an android project, and just after creating it with the wizard Eclipse says that R cannot be resolved, tried to reinstall eclipse and android several times, but it started giving me an error when trying to install the android plugin.
The error says "'Contacting Software Sites' has encountered a problem. HTTP Method Not Allowed: http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html/content.xml"
On the error details says "HTTP Method Not Allowed: http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html/content.xml Http Client connection error response code 405"

How can I fix this!? It's really frustrating and annoying, I know that if I clean the project and rebuild the error should be repaired, but that's not happening.

Comment: Please see this link
[StackOverFlow Question R][1]
[StackOverFlow Question R2][2]



  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4932282/android-r-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-variable
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/885009/r-cannot-be-resolved-android-error

Answer (score 1):

If using Eclipse, run a clean build (`Project/Clean...`); this can often clear issues with the resources not being compiled correctly.

refere this link this will solve this issue [R cannot be resolved - Android error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885009/r-cannot-be-resolved-android-error)

[How To Fix The “R cannot be resolved” Error In Android And Eclipse](http://joshua14.homelinux.org/blog/?p=1202)

Comment: As I stated on the question that does not work at all, I think I may have a corrupt SDK but trying to install it again and I got those error messages "HTTP Method not allowed"