# Eclipse Android has lost APK

Tags: android, eclipse

Few seconds before I was able to launch my apk on the mobile and after I've done refresh and clean project it has lost in some case apk of this application. I'm trying to start it but the Console says:   Android Launch!
[2014-04-21 21:03:49 - StoreUGif] adb is running normally.
[2014-04-21 21:03:49 - StoreUGif] Could not find StoreUGif.apk!

What has happend and how can I get my application back? Please help because I really don't know what has happened.

Comment: Just compile your project again and that will generate a new apk.

Comment: The problem is that it doesen't want to generate it. I'm clicking all the time green arrow but it can not start.

Comment: I've got correct R file but it is still telling me that R can not be resolved to a variable. I'm importing the correct one but nothing happenes

Comment: sometimes refreshing and cleaning loses all the links of ids in R file. Try the solution from this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4932282/android-r-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-variable)

Comment: Make a small change to a class (e.g. add some whitespace) and it should recompile. Alternatively you could rebuild your project by unchecking Project > Build Automatically, then clicking Project > Build Project.

Answer (score 0):

The built .apk will be removed after you clean the project. Try rebuilding your project should generate a new .apk file.

Comment: I've tried it but it still is saying me that can not find it, why still it doesn't want to start?

Answer (score 0):

I know this section is for answers so my solution for this is:

I've had some trashes links in Libraries. Solved it like this: Properties on project -> Android --> Library --> unchecked Is library. That's all.