# Newbie- Errors in main_activity.java in Eclipse

Tags: java

have no experience in Java.Get this error in "R." everywhere in Main_activity.java, when make a new Android project in Eclipse

```
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       if (id == R.id.action_settings)
```

Help appreciated.Thanks

Comment: What error? All you have here are two lines of incomplete code.

Comment: Possible dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4932282/android-r-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-variable

Answer (score 1):

Check if the id action_setting is in your activity_main xml file.
If it is but the error is still there. Go to Projects, try cleaning.

Answer (score 0):

Normally this error happens when you have errors in your xml files (layouts/string/styles etc). Please make sure all the xml files are correct and build the project again.

P.S
IMO Main_activity.java this name is not according to the standard Java naming conventions.As  you are still a newbie to Java/Android I think you better start studying about those basic concepts. That will make your life more easier